# RxJs: How to know which operators closes stream?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, reactivex

I am interested, is there a way to know whether the operator closes a stream or not?
I've been trying to find it in documentation, but with no luck today.

Comment: When you say "close", I guess you are referring unsubscribe? If yes then you have two choices - 1. Either call "unsubscribe()" on subscription object returned by .subscribe() OR 2. Use take(1) operator to complete your subscription once your observable emits 1 value, it will automatically unsubscribe as observable is completed. We will be able to better answer to your question once you provide clarification on what is your mean by "close" stream?

Comment: Streams will *complete* when the subscriber tells the observable there are no more values to emit. None of the operators will trigger the outer observable to *complete*. They can only *lift* an observable and *complete* a new inner observable and *unsubscribe* to the *outer* observable. So even if you use `first()` it will *complete* downstream but can only *unsubscribe* from the upstream observable. If you have a **hot** observable that is emitting values, then it will continue to emit values even if nothing is subscribed.

Comment: @user2216584 exactly what you said, how to I know, for the example you provided, with `take`, that it completes the subscription, i.e automatically unsubscribes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for "`complete`" callback (or third parameter) of subscribe() method [see the detailing in the comments] -

```
yourObservable.pipe(
      take(1) //or take any number of values i.e. which is a finite number,
      map(),
      //or some other operators as per your requirement
    ).subscibe(
      //first call back is to handle the emitted value
      //this will be called every time a new value is emitted by observable
      (value) => {
        //do whatever you want to do with value
        console.log(value);
      },
      //second callback is for handling error
      //This will be called if an observable throws an exception
      //once an exception occurred then also observable complete and no more values recieved by the subscriber
      //Either complete callback is called or error callback is called but not 
      //both
      (exception) => {
        //do whatever you want to do with error
        console.log(error);
      },
      //third callback will be called only when source observable is complete
      //otherwise it will never get called
      //This is the place to know if an observable is completed or not
      //Once complete callback fires, subscription automatically unsubscribed
      () => {
        console.log(`Observable is complete and will not emit any new value`)
      }
    );
```

see the following stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-toarray-xwvtgk?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100